# Архитектурные слои Entity Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Есть проект Net Core WebApi. БД Postrges с orm entity framework core (подход db first). Непонятен один момент. Вот есть например сущность класс Bird в папке Model сгенериный ef со свойством string Name(как в базе данных). Как мне построить архитектуру для создания доп.функционала, чтобы реализовать интерфейс IFly классом Bird, и дальнейшей реализацией этим Bird метода Fly(). Нужно делать слой над сгенеринными моделями EF? Если да, то где можно найти такую инфу? Паттерн -репозиторий, это не то? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Методы в классах моделей EF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157391/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-ef)