# Методы в классах моделей EF

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

В базе данных PostgreSQL есть таблица Birds с полями: id, name. Проект .NET Core с EF (DB first). Сгенерировали класс Birds в EF и теперь вопрос: как можно реализовать интерфейс IFly в этом классе Bird, нужно дополнительный класс (слой) создавать?

Answer (score 1):

Сгенерированный класс имеет модификатор `partial`. Он позволяет добавлять в класс дополнительные члены в другом месте, не трогая сгенерированный код.

Добавляете новый файл с таким же точно определением класса `Birds`: в том же пространстве имён, с модификатором `partial`. В нём реализуете ваш интерфейс и делаете любые другие необходимые изменения.

Получается *один* класс, разбитый на два (или более) файлов.

Где его разместить? Сгенерированные файлы должны быть в одной папке, выделенной для них. Модифицированные вручную - в другой. В том же проекте, в том же слое.

Это не добавляет новый слой.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Многое перечитал по этой теме и про DDD и про паттерн репозиторий писалось.Я уже в них запутался)